# Equation Alignment with Hierarchical Left Alignment

Tags: align

I was able to produce this set of left-aligned equations with aligned indenting to emphasize hierarchy:

[image]

with this code:

```
\begin{align}
  x &= y + z \\
  &\mathrel{\phantom{=}} y = a + b\\
  &\mathrel{\phantom{=}} z = c + d\\
  &\mathrel{\phantom{=y=}}  c = u + v\\
  &\mathrel{\phantom{=}} w = s + t
\end{align}
```

But this feels very hacky. **Q: Is there a better-practice method for doing this?** I tried playing with `falign` to no avail. NOTE: I do intend for the equations to overlap vertically as they're displayed. I don't want them in their own cells, as they would be in an `array` environment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't need all equations numbered, a pair of nested `split` environments can help:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

\[
\begin{split}
  x ={} & y + z \\
      & y = a + b\\
      & \begin{split}
          z ={} & c + d\\
              & c = u + v
        \end{split}\\
      & w = s + t
\end{split}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Update:

In case you need numbered equations, you need `align`, but only one `phantom` is enough.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

\begin{align}
  x ={} & y + z \\
  & y = a + b\\
  & z =  c + d\\
  &\phantom{z ={}}c = u + v\\
  & w = s + t
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This is helpful, but I do actually need the equations numbered. Also, wondering why there's some wonky spacing in the `z=c`

Comment: @lowndrul I've updated the answer with an `align` solution.

Comment: very clever with the `=\ &`. I haven't seen this. Using it did simplify my code.

Comment: if the `=` comes before the `&`, enter it as `={}` to fix the spacing.

Comment: @barbarabeeton Thanks, I didn't know it.